# Mock date constructor with Jasmine

Tags: javascript, mocking, jasmine

I'm testing a function that takes a date as an optional argument. I want to assert that a new Date object is created if the function is called without the argument.

```
var foo = function (date) {
  var d = date || new Date();
  return d.toISOString();
}
```

How do I assert that `new Date` is called?

So far, I've got something like this:

```
it('formats today like ISO-8601', function () {
  spyOn(Date, 'prototype');
  expect().toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```

See: https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies

Comment: Don't spies do this? I'm not sure you need to mock the date. Are you genuinely concerned you'll slip up and start returning a day ago or something? https://github.com/pivotal/jasmine/wiki/Spies

Comment: Does this work? spyOn(window,"Date")

Comment: I was getting different dates back actually. Timezone thing...

Comment: None of these answers seem to work in an async test with Karma :(. always get `Error: Timeout - Async function did not complete within 5000ms (set by jasmine.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL)`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Credit to @HMR.  Test I wrote to verify:

```
  it('Should spy on Date', function() {
    var oldDate = Date;
    spyOn(window, 'Date').andCallFake(function() {
      return new oldDate();
    });
    var d = new Date().toISOString;
    expect(window.Date).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
```

Comment: With such solution `Date.prototype` is get replaced with spy one, is there a wait to workaround it as well?

Comment: For the users who are using Edge version of *Jasmine*:
`
 it('Should spy on Date', function() {
    var oldDate = Date;
    // and.callFake
    spyOn(window, 'Date').and.callFake(function() {
      return new oldDate();
    });
    var d = new Date().toISOString;
    expect(window.Date).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
`

Comment: This is not the way to go!! use jasmine.clock() instead

Comment: This will break things like Date.now().  Don't use it.

Answer (score 109):

from jasmine example,

```
jasmine.clock().install();
var baseTime = new Date(2013, 9, 23);
jasmine.clock().mockDate(baseTime);
jasmine.clock().tick(50)
expect(new Date().getTime()).toEqual(baseTime.getTime() + 50);


afterEach(function () {
    jasmine.clock().uninstall();
});
```

[jasmine date](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_Date)

Comment: This should be the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: This is the best way of mocking Date()

Comment: It works like a charm. For me is the best answer, thanks

Answer (score 9):

for me it worked with:

```
spyOn(Date, 'now').and.callFake(function() {
    return _currdate;
  });
```

instead of `.andCallFake` (using "grunt-contrib-jasmine": "^0.6.5", that seems to include jasmine 2.0.0)

Comment: That's not mocking the constructor?

Answer (score 6):

For me it worked by just using `mockDate()` without anything else:

```
jasmine.clock().mockDate(new Date('2000-01-01T01:01:01'));
```

Answer (score 3):

this worked for me

```
var baseTime = new Date().getTime();
spyOn(window, 'Date').and.callFake(function() {
   return {getTime: function(){ return baseTime;}};
});
```

Answer (score 1):

For the users who are using Edge version of *Jasmine*:

```
it('Should spy on Date', function() {
    var oldDate = Date;

    // and.callFake
    spyOn(window, 'Date').and.callFake(function() {
        return new oldDate();
    });

    var d = new Date().toISOString;

    expect(window.Date).toHaveBeenCalled();
});
```