# Mocking the constructor function only in Javascript (using spyOn)

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, mocking, jasmine, spy

I'm doing something like this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152796/mock-date-constructor-with-jasmine) which allows me to provide my own implementation of the `Date` constructor in my test

```
spyOn(window, 'Date').andCallFake(function() {
  return SOME_DATE;
});
```

I've now run into an issue where I want to upgrade moment.js and they're using additional Date functions in the code that I am calling with my mocked Date object.  These functions don't exist:

```
Date.UTC() // doesn't exist in mocked date when accessed in moment.js
```

So I think what I need to do is somehow mock only the constructor function of `Date` and let the other functions off of it pass through.

I've tried various forms of `.andCallThrough` as well as assigning the functions that it needs to the spy object to no avail (e.g., `spy.UTC = OldDate.UTC`).  Any ideas?

Comment: Why not mock moment.js also?

Comment: @Schleis that's an interesting thought and I'll likely try it.  I'm still curious if there's a nice way to do what I'm wanting here.

Comment: So mocking moment.js is a bit of a design change, as it's not on window.  I'd have to change my service to inject it instead of requireing it in (I think at least)..