# jasmine spyOn on javascript new Date

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am unit testing the my client code in angulajs and i understand this code means

```
 var newdate = new Date(2013,6,29);
    spyOn(Date.prototype, 'getTime').and.callFake(function() {
          return newdate;
        });
```

we mockout the getTime() methode of the Date object. but i want to mock out the new Date() instead. for example the code i want to test contains this line

```
payload.created_at = new Date();
```

I dont have access to payload.created_at. so i want to tell jasmine that whenever you see new Date(), replace that with a given date i give you. So  i was thinking of something like but it doesnt work.

```
spyOn(Date.prototype, 'new Date').and.callFake(function() {
          return newdate;
        });
```

but new Date is not a method of the Date. Please can someone help me figure this out? thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152796/mock-date-constructor-with-jasmine

Comment: I tried that, it didnt work. it gave me an undefined error

Comment: What undefined error?

Comment: @PSL , no worries, the link helped me figure out an answer. I posted my answer. Thanks

Comment: Ok. That is just difference in the the jasmine version (which you should have know already since in the question you are doing `and.callFake`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so this link [[Mock date constructor with Jasmine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152796/mock-date-constructor-with-jasmine][1]) had the answer but it wasn't working for me for some reason. I guess it might i have to do with my jasmine version but below is the code that worked for me

```
var oldDate = new Date();
    spyOn(window, 'Date').and.callFake(function() {
      return oldDate;
    });
```

there is a difference in the .and.callFake of the code above and that in the link above. Thanks

Answer (score 19):

The [Jasmine Clock](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Jasmine_Clock) api allows you to fake out the JavaScript Date functionality without manually writing a spy for it.

In particular, read the section about [mocking the date](http://jasmine.github.io/2.2/introduction.html#section-Mocking_the_Date).

```
describe("Mocking the Date object", function(){
    beforeEach(function() {
      jasmine.clock().install();
    });

    it("mocks the Date object and sets it to a given time", function() {
      var baseTime = new Date(2013, 9, 23);

      jasmine.clock().mockDate(baseTime);

      jasmine.clock().tick(50);
      expect(new Date().getTime()).toEqual(baseTime.getTime() + 50);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
      jasmine.clock().uninstall();
    });
});
```

Comment: This should be accepted answer.