# What's an efficient way to testing date functions using Jasmine?

Tags: jasmine, karma-jasmine

let's say I have two functions

```
var now = new Date();
var oneDayAgo = now.getTime() - (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
var beforeOneDay = [];
var otherEvents = [];

var assignTimeSlots = function(time) {

    if (time < oneDayAgo)
        beforeOneDay.push(time)
    else
        otherEvents.push(time)

}
```

What would be a good way to test time using jasmine?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mock date constructor with Jasmine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26152796/mock-date-constructor-with-jasmine)

Answer (score 0):

**Your Challenge**

I assume what you are really interested in is testing your `assignTimeSlots` function. What is giving you a challenge is that it depends on your global `oneDayAgo` variable defined outside the function. This means your test, and the code are both dependent on that global field, which makes things challenging, especially when it is using the current time, which changes each time the test is run.

**Dependency Injection**

You can get work around this problem by injecting that variable into the function as an argument. This allows you to control what the current time is in your tests. You are no longer coupled to the system clock.

**Example**

The following is untested, but should get the point across...

```
var assignTimeSlots = function(oneDayAgo, time) {
  if (time < oneDayAgo)
    beforeOneDay.push(time)
  else
    otherEvents.push(time)
}

it ('should be added to "beforeOneDay" if it is prior to yesterday', function() {
  var oneDayAgo = new Date(2017, 1, 27, 13, 35);
  var now = new Date(2017, 1, 28, 13, 36);
  assignTimeSlots(now, oneDayAgo);
  expect(beforeOneDay[0]).toBe(now);
  expect(otherEvents.length).toBe(0);
});
```

Comment: hmm...so how will we make sure we do not just hardcode a time in the test cases to ensure any dates will work with the function?

Comment: Call it twice with two different `oneDayAgo` values.

Comment: but that means we will need to change the test cases every time we run the test cases.   `oneDayAgo` is dependent on the current time, so if we hardcode the dates in the tests, the tests won't be useful a few weeks from now.

Comment: "I assume what you are really interested in is testing your assignTimeSlots function". If you change your function to how I have defined it, where the time is passed in, it doesn't matter where the time comes from. It sounds like you are trying to test more than the `assignTimeSlots` function. My answer is _only_ if you are trying to test that function.

Comment: The function I provided was just an example, and unfortunately changing the arguments of the function isn't an option